# Creating random pixeled lines in Proccesing

Tags: random, processing

I'm trying to make a game and I'm stuck on random level design. Basically, I'm trying to create a line from one edge/corner to another edge/corner while having some randomness to it.

See below image 1 [link broken] and 2 for examples. I'm doing this in [processing](https://processing.org/) and every attempt I've tried hasn't yielded proper results. I can get them to populate randomly but not in a line or from edge to edge. I'm trying to do this on a 16 x 16 grid by the way. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: Link to image is broken.  Could you please post the non-workable code that you need help with?

Comment: What do you need, a grid of objects, an image of a grid? Is the grid the whole level or do you need to connect it to other grids? Also your current code would be appreciated. Sorry for editing your post, I tried to make it more friendly to this community to better your chances at getting help ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the challenge is in having a connected line from top to bottom with a bit of randomness driving left/right direction.

There are multiple options.

Here's a basic idea that comes to mind:

- pick a starting x position: left's say right down the middle
- for each row from 0 to 15 (for 16 px level)

  - pick a random between 3 numbers:

    - if it's the 1st go left (x decrements)
    - if it's the 2nd go right (x increments)
    - if it's the 3rd: ignore: it means the line will go straight down for this iteration

Here's a basic sketch that illustrates this using `PImage` to visualise the data:

```java
void setup(){
  size(160, 160);
  noSmooth();
  
  int levelSize = 16;
  
  PImage level = createImage(levelSize, levelSize, RGB);
  level.loadPixels();
  java.util.Arrays.fill(level.pixels, color(255));
  
  int x = levelSize / 2;
  for(int y = 0 ; y < levelSize; y++){
    int randomDirection = (int)random(3);
    if(randomDirection == 1) x--;
    if(randomDirection == 2) x++;
    // if randomDirection is 0 ignore as we don't change x -> just go down
    // constrain to valid pixel
    x = constrain(x, 0, levelSize - 1);
    // render dot
    level.pixels[x + y * levelSize] = color(0);
  }
  
  level.updatePixels();
  
  // render result;
  image(level, 0, 0, width, height);
  fill(127);
  text("click to reset", 10, 15);
}

// hacky reset
void draw(){}
void mousePressed(){
  setup();
}
```

The logic is be pretty plain above, but free to replace `random(3)` with other options (perhaps [throwing dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musikalisches_W%C3%BCrfelspiel) to determine direction or exploring other psuedo-random number generators (PRNGs) such as [`randomGaussian()`](https://processing.org/reference/randomGaussian_.html), [`noise()`](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) (and related functions), etc.)

Here's a p5.js version of the above:

```js
let levelSize = 16;
let numBlocks = levelSize * levelSize;
let level = new Array(numBlocks);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 320);
  
  level.fill(0);
  let x = floor(levelSize / 2);
  for(let y = 0 ; y < levelSize; y++){
    let randomDirection = floor(random(3));
    if(randomDirection === 1) x--;
    if(randomDirection === 2) x++;
    // if randomDirection is 0 ignore as we don't change x -> just go down
    // constrain to valid pixel
    x = constrain(x, 0, levelSize - 1);
    // render dot
    level[x + y * levelSize] = 1;
  }
  
  // optional: print to console
  // prettyPrintLevel(level, levelSize, numBlocks); 
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  // visualise
  for(let i = 0 ; i < numBlocks; i++){
    let x = i % levelSize;
    let y = floor(i / levelSize);
    fill(level[i] == 1 ? color(0) : color(255));
    rect(x * 20, y * 20, 20, 20);
  }
}

function prettyPrintLevel(level, levelSize, numBlocks){
  for(let i = 0; i < numBlocks; i+= levelSize){
    print(level.slice(i, i + levelSize));
  }
}

function mousePressed(){
  setup(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

The data is a structured a 1D array in both examples, however, if it makes it easier it could easily be a 2D array. At this stage of development, whatever is the simplest, most readable option is the way to go.